# "Unable to resolve path to module" error in VSCode for React Native Expo application

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

I'm developing a react native app in Expo and have recently received the following error messages in VSCode: "Unable to resolve path to module"

The error message is not displayed during **relative imports** or **node module imports**. However, all other imports show the error message.

What's interesting is that 1) VSCode's "Quick Fix" generates these imports, 2) right-clicking "Go to Definition" successfully locates the file, and 3) the imports actually work. Despite this, the error message "Unable to resolve path to module" persists.

Here's my tsconfig.json file.

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": ["ES2021"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./src/*"],
    },
    "rootDirs": ["./", "./src/"]
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "index.js"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "aws"]
}
```

Here's my directory
Project/
src/
/store
/actions
tsconfig.json
package.json
node_modules
index.js

Example of import with the issue described above.

For a file defined as Project/src/store/actions/actions.ts

`import { MakeRequest, REQUEST_TYPE } from 'store/fetch';` shows error message (other import based on tsconfig)

`import { MakeRequest, REQUEST_TYPE } from '../fetch';` succeeds (relative import)